# How to call java script function using thymeleaf attribute th:href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have written like this in my HTML page:

```
 <a th:href="@{javascript:deleteContact('deletemainmenu?id=${var[0]}')}">
 </a>
```

And my script is:

```
 function deleteContact(url)
 {
     var isOK = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");
     if(isOK)
     {
       go(url);
      }
 }
```

It's showing an error:

> Could not parse as expression: "`@{javascript:deleteContact('deletemainmenu?id=${var[0]}')}`"

How can i call javascript using `th:href`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function deleteContact(url)
     {
         var isOK = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");
         if(isOK)
         {
           go(url);
          }
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:deleteContact('param value')">Test </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I've already tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getkey(a) 
    {
        var pms =  document.getElementById("textkey").value;
        a.href = '/allTransaction' + pms;
    }
</script>

<input  id="textkey" type="text" name="">
<a href="" onclick="getkey(this)">gogogo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you wanted is something like that

```
function myFunction(name,t) {
...
}

<a class="nav-link" th:href="'javascript:myFunction(&quot'+${category}+'&quot,1);'">
```